# Angular 17 unable to debug using chrome tools

Tags: angular, angular17

I have given sourceMap= true in angular.json and tsconfig.json. I still do not see the source map in chrome tools

[image]

Comment: please share the contents of `angular.json`!

Comment: You can look-up the files with by searching for them win ctrl+p !

Comment: In a newly generated Angular 17 project, it works. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Error from my side. Posted answer. Apologies if this caused any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

This was an error from my side. I was using npm start with a different configuration. I missed to add sourceMap=true inside that particular configuration.

```
ng serve --configuration custom

 "custom": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [                         
               
                            ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true
            }
```